# Performance hit if each thread has to access identical array

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, memory

I have a computationally demanding task that I am going to spread out over multiple threads. Each thread will require access to the identical, large `String[][]`. I am wondering whether the fact that they all need to access the same `String[][]` on heap will hit performance? Would it be better to make copies of this `String[][]` for each thread to access individually (even though they all only need to access the identical instance of this `String[][]`)?

Note that, for `String[][] someArray = new String[100][1000000];` (for example),  it is improbable that at any single point in time they will be calling the same `someArray[i]` at the same time. Generally each thread will be using a different `i` at any given point in time. However sometimes `i` will be the same across threads (mostly by chance).

Each thread will be read-only on `someArray`.

Comment: When you write 'need _access_', do you need to read it or write it, too?

Comment: Do the threads mutate the array? If so you need to think about locking and resource starvation. Otherwise JIT will cache local copies if it thinks it would help.

Comment: @tilois Read-only. No writing or changing anything whatsoever.

Comment: Then you can share a single instance of your array safely and there won't be a performance hit.

Comment: If it is possible to modify the thread to use list instead of array, you can convert your array to list and get an immutable list. I have not tested but believe accessing from immutable list should be faster if accessed simultaneously in multiple threads.

Comment: @Parvez this seems to be nonsense. What is an "immutable list"? Where does it come from? Does it perhaps use an array to store its data under the hood? In which case how does that make things faster?

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Yes it may be nonsense but I was thinking that someArray is a shared object for multiple threads and jvm may choose to cache it locally for each thread. If this shared object is immutable jvm doesn't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only reading the values then it shouldn't be a problem. It doesn't even matter if they are reading the same 'i'. The problems come when you start writing to shared memory...

EDIT: Removed confusing synchronization comment.

Comment: If there is synchronization is it a problem if they read the same `i` (in terms of performance)?

Comment: @user2763361 yes, of course. Synchronization has a **massive** cost, orders of magnitude we're talking. Moreover, two threads _cannot_ read the same `i` if there is synchronization - that's the whole point. So you have to add the cost of potential resource starvation to the already large cost of synchronizing at all.

Comment: You can't really synchronise a single array element so not really an issue. You'd either lock the whole thing or nothing at all in which case 'i' is irrelevant. Sharing read only data will give no problems. There is no need to synchronize read only data.

Comment: @nicktalbot Synchronizing a single array element may be of no use, but it certainly isn't impossible. You'll just need a lot of locks.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik Yes it is *possible* with additional objects